# How to automate (copy) LDAP/Kereberos install

Tags: debian, rsync, openldap, uuid

I have several machines running Debian that I'm configuring to work with Kerberos and LDAP. I thought I would automate using `rsync`. 
At first I tried a basic `rsync` clone excluding directories and files such as /run, /sys, /etc/fstab, /etc/hosts, etc. That failed -- somehow, some file specifying a UUID got copied (and given the files I omitted, I'm unsure what it could have been). 
So I decided a more refined approach - using `find -mmin -90` to locate all the files altered within the last 90 minutes (excluding /proc, /dev, etc.). However, that too failed with an unclear to me transfer of UUID specification.

Comment: I think you would be better off actually copy *specific* files, rather than trying to copy everything and *exclude* certain files.  Consider a configuration management tool (Ansible/Chef/Puppet/etc) to help keep things automated and consistent.

Comment: Yeah. I was thinking about implementing Puppet or Chef, but I was hoping to get things going by copying the exact files needed using rysnc --- but identifying them with find didn't work out too well for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you should use the distribution's package manager (`apt`) to install software, and proper configuration management tools (eg, Ansible/Chef/Puppet as mentioned in a comment, or Debian's local debconf) to propagate site-specific information and files. Copying files in bulk is not a good approach.

If you have recently configured one machine by hand and want to replicate that setup on other machines, the [`blueprint`](http://devstructure.com/blueprint/) tool might be just what you need. It will identify a list of packages installed (using `apt-get` in the case of Debian), configuration files (eg, in `/etc/`), and even any binaries compiled and installed manually in `/usr/local/`. This tool can be used to create chef and puppet scripts automatically; otherwise you will need to encode all the installation and configuration steps you already did by hand.

It may be too late in your case, but in the future you might want to install the `etckeeper` package for debian, which will automatically version control the contents of `/etc/`, which makes identifying and documenting your changes (including the installation/upgrade/removal) of packages much easier.

If you will be installing Debian from scratch on more than a couple machines, you might want to look in to tools for debian "pre-seeding", or custom image generation tools like FAI or Debian Live. See also answers to "[automated linux deployment and config management at small scale - is it worth it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/32840/automated-linux-deployment-and-config-management-at-small-scale-is-it-worth-it)".

Comment: blueprint looks superb. I'm not sure how many problems etckeeper will solve at this point. I felt I had some compelling reason not to use Debian-Edu or DebianLan, but as I progress I wish I'd considered pre-seeding & Puppet.